# django default foreign key value for users

Tags: python, django, mysql-error-1067

I've had a read through http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/ but still am having problems migrating my new db schema with a ForeignKey for a user in a list of products

a simplified version of my code is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# other imports

class Product(models.Model):

 author = models.ForeignKey(User)
 # other product fields..
```

but when I try to migrate to South, and this may be the problem, as my user database is not handled by South (??forgive my newbieness) i'm getting errors that a default value needs to be set:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1067, "Invalid default value for 'author_id'")
```

Can anyone explain what i'm doing wrong?? Ideally I wouldn't want a default value for the user, or at least null, false or 0 (but that doesn't seem to work)..

many thanks,

adam

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be possible to have an empty value for `author`, you need to define the ForeignKey with `null=True`. You'll probably want `blank=True` as well, as that controls the validation in Django forms.

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Ah thanks for you're help, still getting the same error though? running "python manage.py schemamigration search --auto" gives me 3 options: 1)quit now an add a default to the field (null=True, blank=True??) 2) specify a one-off value for existing columns (there aren't any) 3) disable the backwards migration by raising an exception (??!)

Comment: ..interestingly the form view does recognize the foreign relation, so the migration to south seems to be the problem.. highly confused!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up taking the easy route and totally resetting the product table, and migrating from scratch which worked. Not sure i've learnt anything (other than how to reset an app)!